# DAX - Incremental Index after first occurrence

Tags: indexing, dax

Hi DAX experts around the world !

I need your help with simple (I think) index column but I can't figure it out. 
As you see in the below image, I need to create an index column which will show 0 where ITEMS = 0 and after first ITEMS occurrence it will create an index and increment with 1 going forward. If you have any clue how to obtain it.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index could be a count of rows with nonzero items and that day or earlier.

```
Index =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        Table1,
        Table1[Items] > 0 &&
        Table1[Date] <= EARLIER ( Table1[Date] )
    )
) + 0
```

The `+ 0` forces it return `0` instead of `BLANK()` when counting empty tables.

Comment: Hi Alexis, **Thank you!** Your solution works as it should. I have one more question...Imagine in this table next to Cars in the Product table we have also Phones and many other products and other columns are with the same logic. How would you wrote the code to create a separate index **for each Product** ?

Comment: You could add another condition to the filter. `&& Table1[Product] = EARLIER(Table1[Product])`.